# How do I collect from a nested iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to collect from a nested iterator and I get a `FromIterator` not implemented error. Here's an example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum DayStatus {
    Normal,
    Abnormal,
}

struct Week {
    days: Vec<Day>,
}

struct Day {
    status: DayStatus,
}

struct Month {
    weeks: Vec<Week>,
}

fn get_abnormal_days(month: Month) -> Vec<Day> {
    // assume we have a month: Month which is filled
    month
        .weeks
        .iter()
        .map(|w| w.days.iter().filter(|d| d.status == DayStatus::Abnormal))
        .collect()
}

fn main() {}
```

Gives me:

```
 error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<Day>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<'_, Day>, [closure@src/main.rs:24:39: 24:74]>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:25:10
   |
25 |         .collect()
   |          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Day>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<'_, Day>, [closure@src/main.rs:24:39: 24:74]>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<'_, Day>, [closure@src/main.rs:24:39: 24:74]>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<Day>`
```

I could try to `impl` the `FromIterator` but the type it has to be from seems too inner to be deal with. I think I'm not calling the proper `collect` or maybe `map` but I can't see what I'm missing

My first attempt tried to return `&[Day]` but it was failing as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unnest the iterator, use `flat_map` instead of `map`.

Furthermore, you need to either use `Copy` types or use `into_iter` to iterate over owned values and not just references.

Working example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum DayStatus {
    Normal,
    Abnormal,
}

struct Week {
    days: Vec<Day>,
}

struct Day {
    status: DayStatus,
}

struct Month {
    weeks: Vec<Week>,
}

fn get_abnormal_days(month: Month) -> Vec<Day> {
    // assume we have a month: Month which is filled
    month
        .weeks
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|w| {
            w.days
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|d| d.status == DayStatus::Abnormal)
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight, my example has a mistake: `Week`'s `days` is `[Day; 7]` rather than `Vec<Day>`. Does it make any difference? I'm asking because I'm still facing an error: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<timedata::flexday::FlexDay>` cannot be
built from an iterator over elements of type `&timedata::flexday::FlexDay`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&timedata::flexday::FlexDay>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<timedata::flexday::FlexDay>`

Comment: It does make difference but I don't get why. Adding `to_vec()` before `into_iter()` does the trick, but I don't understand what's happening here :-/